# 01 Suzuki marauder VT 800 downshift stalls

Tags: motorcycle, stall

My 01suzuki marauder VT 800 stalls on the down shift as if I hit the kill switch what can cause this any suggestions

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could be a clutch sensor possibly. I'm not familiar with this exact bike, so I don't have tons of insight.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the clutch switch would be related. It usually only affects starting, as once the bike is running the clutch is expected to be both in an out in gear and in neutral. Can you pinpoint exactly when the engine dies? I'm guessing the press down on the shifter is what does it?

Comment: On the down shift it self as soon as I hit the shifter

Comment: It was the clutch switch and the gear box I got it back yesterday and it seems to be fine

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say, as it could be any number of things. My best guess would be the sidestand switch. Your left foot is shifting, which is kicking down. It's possible your foot is catching the sidestand, or the force on the peg is affecting it. If the sensor detects that the sidestand is down while the bike is not in neutral, it will kill the engine. Usually, this is by cutting off the ignition circuit, so ignition coils and fuel injection stops.

I would inspect the sensor, and if it looks ok, try temporarily bypassing the switch and see if the problem persists.

Comment: It's at the shop now they put a new fuel filter fuel pump and clutch in its all under warranty still but it dose not die on the downshift for them it is not happening all the time and I suggested the kickstand switch they put a new one on and it still did it  should I ask them to bypass

Comment: If they replaced the kickstand switch and it's still happening, it's very unlikely that both were faulty. Can't really think of what else would cause something like this, apart from a bad electrical connection somewhere.